# UITabBarController and UINavigationController

Tags: iphone

i have a UITabBarController application,and i want to have a UINavigationController in one of the tab,so how can i achieve this thanks advance for help

Answer (score 3):

http://www.cimgf.com/2009/06/25/uitabbarcontroller-with-uinavigationcontroller-using-interface-builder/

Answer (score 1):

i prefer to do it programmatically
here is an [example of how to use uinavigationcontroller and uitabbarcontroller](http://www.ccsprite.com/ios/uinavigationcontroller-uitabbarcontroller-example-programmatically.html)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Always make sure and post your code here as well. These questions are for future reference and that link might not always be there.