# A basic UITabBar Application

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I'm creating a really basic iOS Application. I have a TabViewController with 5 tabs, I'd like to create sub pages from each tab. What's the best way to do this? Should I be using more tabs or can I use a ViewController that will inherit the tabbar? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: May I direct you to the lovely [search box](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Uitabbar) that this site has, good sir?  Possible dupes:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750706/uitabbarcontroller-and-uinavigationcontroller http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011262/is-there-a-good-uitabbarcontroller-example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207525/iphone-uitabbarcontroller

Answer (score 1):

By sub pages, are you referring to pushing a new page onto the stack, or presenting a new page over top of the current one?

In the case of the former, you'd be looking to pass in a UINavigationController as the view controller for the tab, and have the original view controller for that tab as the RootViewController for the navigation controller.

In the case of the latter, you can just present a new view controller using the presentModalViewController method of the current view controller.